# SQL Query within a Partition By statement in BigQuery

Tags: sql

I want to run a query where the column by which to partition by is picked up from another table. The idea is to write a generic skeleton script, and in the future change the where clause in the partition by to a dynamic quantity.

In BigQuery, we have the following table available, which tells us the primary key for each table, PK_TABLE:

| table_name | column_name |
| --- | --- |
| sometable | id |

What I'd like to do, is for each table in the database, run a script like this:

```sql
SELECT * 
from (
  SELECT *, 
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY 
            (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM PK_TABLE WHERE TABLE_NAME='SOMETABLE') 
                ORDER BY TIME DESC) AS RANK
  FROM SOMETABLE
  ) A 
WHERE A.RANK=1
```

I would expect the above table to return the exact same result as the following code:

```sql
SELECT * 
from (
  SELECT *, 
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TIME DESC) AS RANK
  FROM SOMETABLE
  ) A 
WHERE A.RANK=1
```

But the two results are incredibly different. Is what I am trying with the first script possible?

The only reason I can think that the results are different is when I use a SELECT statement in PARTITION BY, it probably uses it as a literal and computes an unexpected results, as opposed to actually passing a column name to the query.

Would be good to have this validated.

Comment: Tag spam doesn't help us help you; it makes it harder to. Tagging multiple conflicting tags means that we have no idea what technology you are really asking about, making your question unclear and difficult to answer. Tagging completely irrelevant technologies just wastes the time of the subject experts you attract that know nothing about the technology you are *actually* asking about. Either way, tag spam can easily end up attracting downvotes and also close votes if they make the question unclear. Just tag the technologies you are actually asking about.  I've removed the conflicting tags.

Comment: You can't dynamically reference a column name in sql. You will need to write this sql inside of a script where the script gets the `column_name `from `pk_table` and builds the SQL string that is then executed. You are correct that your current attempt is partitioning on the constant returned by your `SELECT`.

Comment: @JNevill is wrong  you xab use dynamic sql https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-dynamic-sql-in-bigquery-8c04dcc0f0de

Comment: @nbk "Dynamic SQL" is EXACLTY what I was talking about. Generally in every RDBMS this is a feature of stored procedures which is, in my mind, under the umbrella of "Scripting". You have to run 2 sql statements to pull this off, one to get dB object dynamically to concatenate or parameterize into your sql string, and then something like `execute immediate` to run the sql you built. Just because this has been code-golf'd in that linked example, doesn't mean it isn't two steps.

Comment: The reason you can't do it in one statement/execution is because without the object (which has to be determined dynamically as a first step) the database can't create the execution path.

Comment: All that being said, I think that link is a great source for building and executing the dynamic sql without much overhead. It would be worthy of an answer if the relevant parts are pulled from the source into the answer.

Comment: @nbk thanks a ton, the link helped significantly.

Comment: @JNevill, thanks for your replies. with your comments and the link, I was able to find a solution. Will post it in a few mins. Also thanks for the confirmation that it's impossible without a dynamic SQL code.

Comment: @Larnu thanks for the edit and apologies. I was particularly trying to tag the SQL problem on big-query that I was facing. Hence the broader tags. Will be mindful in the future.

Comment: If you're using Big Query then just tag [[tag:google-bigquery]] along side [[tag:sql]] then, @Akshay . SQL Server and MySQL are *completely* different technologies/

Comment: @Larnu oh yes, my bad, totally should have not added SQL Server and MySQL!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @JNevill and @ndk's post, the solution is to create a dynamic SQL with two steps.

For those who don't want to go through the link, the solution looks like this:

```sql
DECLARE col0 string;
set col0 = (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM PK_TABLE WHERE TABLE_NAME='SOMETABLE')

EXECUTE IMMEDIATELY format('''
SELECT * 
from (
  SELECT *, 
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY %s ORDER BY TIME DESC) AS RANK
  FROM SOMETABLE
  ) A 
WHERE A.RANK=1
''', col0);
```